# Replace and change column values while merging

Tags: r, merge

I am merging two tables created as data frame

```
chairs <- data.frame(sales.rep = c("bob", "tom"), sales = c(5,7) )

tables <- data.frame(sales.rep = c("bob", "john"),sales = c(55,77) )

merge(x = chairs, y = tables, by = "sales.rep", all = F)
```

the result is

```
 sales.rep  sales.x sales.y
1       bob       5      55
```

I have two questions.  How can I create only one column where the `sales.x` is over-written by `sales.y`?  Like following:

```
   sales.rep   sales
1       bob     55
```

second question is if there is a way to do an outer join and have only one sales column with sales values coming from `sales.y` unless `sales.y` is NA.  Like the following:

```
  sales.rep  sales sales.y
1       bob     55
2       tom      7
3      john     77
```

in other words, I only need values from `sales.y` unless it is NA.

Any help is much appreciate in advance!

Comment: Take it step by step. Use the value of sales.y in a new dataframe and change the name of the column.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, what you want to get out of the merge is already your tables dataframe. You can't use merge with just one column, as there would be nothing to merge.
If you would have more columns and wanted to ignore one let's say you had :

```
chairs <- data.frame(sales.rep = c("bob", "tom"),colour=c("blue","red"), sales = c(5,7) )
```

then you could get

```
merge(x=chairs[,1:2],y=tables)
```

which gives you

```
 sales.rep colour sales 
1       bob   blue    55
```

Second:
Go one step at a time here:

```
tmp <- merge(x=chairs,y=tables,by=c('sales.rep'),all=T)
tmp$sales.x[is.na(tmp$sales.x)] <- tmp$sales.y[is.na(tmp$sales.x)]
tmp$sales.y<-""
names(tmp)[3]<-"sales"
```

Comment: could you please mark it as solved, if this one works for you?

Comment: It works but your assignment in the second stop does not quite get me the result I wanted, which is set sales.x to sales.y if !is.na(sales.y) is true. I went for following assignment modifying yours slightly. df.new$sales.x[!is.na(df.new$sales.y)] <-
   df.new$sales.y[!is.na(df.new$sales.y)]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a`data.table` solution for the first question: do an inner join with a subset of chairs that does not to include the "sales" column:

```
library(data.table)
chairs <- data.table(chairs)
tables <- data.table(tables)

tables[chairs[,!"sales",with=F], nomatch=0L, on = "sales.rep"]
```

Second question, you'll have to go step by step.

Comment: the answer gave me an erro.  also n your tables statement you only mention chairs and not table.

Comment: I have edited the ansewer, first you'll need to convert your df's to data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no one step.  I have been using SAS for a while and SAS has one nice data merge feature in which you can do such tricks in one merge step.  Having said that, thanks for those who helped and looking over code from others, here is what worked for me

```
chairs <- data.frame(sales.rep = c("bob", "tom"), sales = c(5,7) )

tables <- data.frame(sales.rep = c("bob", "john"),sales = c(55,77) )

df.new <- merge(x = chairs, y = tables, by = "sales.rep", all = T)

df.new$sales.x[!is.na(df.new$sales.y)] <-
   df.new$sales.y[!is.na(df.new$sales.y)]

df.new$sales <- df.new$sales.x

df.new <- df.new[c("sales.rep","sales")]
```

this gives me what I wanted, which is the following result:

```
> df.new
  sales.rep sales
1       bob    55
2       tom     7
3      john    77
```

The above data frame gives me values from sales.y when sales.y is not missing and when it is missing it gives me values from sales.x.